# Need help sending correct payload to update State

Tags: reactjs, mongodb-stitch, react-context

I am using MongoDB-Stitch application to create a phonebook app. When I update a user the information gets saved correctly in the database but it won't show on the client until after I refresh the page. I believe the issue is in my reducer with the **action.payload._id** but I'm not really sure if that is it. 
Reducer

````
    case 'updateContact':
        return {
          ...state,
            contacts: state.contacts.map((contact) =>
              contact._id === action.payload._id? action.payload : contact
            ),
            loading: false,
        };```
    Action
    ```const updateContact = async (contactId, contact) => {
            const query = { _id: contactId };
            const update = {
                $set: {
                    contact,
                },
            };
            const options = { upsert: false };
            await items.updateOne(query, update, options);
            dispatch({
                type: 'updateContact',
                payload: [contact, contactId],
            });
        };
````

My data is stored like this:

````
    contacts: [
       {
          "_id":"5eb0c9238016c9de09f3d307",
          "contact":{
             "name":"Anne Bonny",
             "email":"anne@bonny.com",
             "phone":"3213231423"
          },
          "owner_id":"5ea89a7e94861451f4c4fe6f"
       },
       {
          "_id":"5eb0c93f8016c9de09f3d308",
          "contact":{
             "name":"Woodes Rogers",
             "email":"woodes@rogers.com",
             "phone":"3217037475"
          },
          "owner_id":"5ea89a7e94861451f4c4fe6f"
       },
       {
          "contact":{
             "name":"john silver",
             "email":"longjohn@silver.com",
             "phone":"9391032314"
          },
          "owner_id":"5ea89a7e94861451f4c4fe6f",
          "_id":"5eb19220a6949dfb5c76e30b"
       },
       {
          "contact":{
             "name":"Charles Vane",
             "email":"charles@vane.com",
             "phone":"3921303921"
          },
          "owner_id":"5ea89a7e94861451f4c4fe6f",
          "_id":"5eb19234a6949dfb5c76e30c"
       }
    ]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sent **payload as an array** with `contactId` and `contact` to reducer, where you are expecting the payload to have `_id` field in reducer. You probably just need to send the contact and use the `_id` field from it assuming the contact sent to update contact is of the format

```
 {
      "_id":"5eb0c93f8016c9de09f3d308",
      "contact":{
         "name":"Woodes Rogers",
         "email":"woodes@rogers.com",
         "phone":"3217037475"
      },
      "owner_id":"5ea89a7e94861451f4c4fe6f"
   },
```

Change your action to below code to make it work

```
   const updateContact = async (contactId, contact) => {
        const query = { _id: contactId };
        const update = {
            $set: {
                contact,
            },
        };
        const options = { upsert: false };
        await items.updateOne(query, update, options);
        dispatch({
            type: 'updateContact',
            payload: contact,
        });
    };
```

In case your contact object is simply of the below format

```
  {
         "name":"Woodes Rogers",
         "email":"woodes@rogers.com",
         "phone":"3217037475"
      },
```

You would need to pass on the contactId separately and update your reducer too like below

```
   const updateContact = async (contactId, contact) => {
        const query = { _id: contactId };
        const update = {
            $set: {
                contact,
            },
        };
        const options = { upsert: false };
        await items.updateOne(query, update, options);
        dispatch({
            type: 'updateContact',
            payload: { contact, contactId },
        });
    };
```

and reducer will be as follows

```
case 'updateContact':
    return {
      ...state,
        contacts: state.contacts.map((contact) =>
          contact._id === action.payload.contactId ? { ...contact, contact: action.payload.contact } : contact
        ),
        loading: false,
    };
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I looked in the dev tools and payload is only sending the contact object with what is to be updated. There is no id being sent to match the `contact._id === action.payload.id` would I send the id in the payload like this `payload: {contact, contactId}`? if so how I would I change the reducer to have it equal each other?